# Lotus Domino cannot move subdocuments from one document to another?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Our Domino developer told us that it is "technologically impossible" to move subdocuments between documents. Is this true?

Earlier this year he wrote for us a course registration system with the following database diagram:

[image: database diagram]

Now we asked him how to move waitlisted registrants from the full training sessions to those sessions that are not.  He said it is impossible.  He said we need to re-enter (recreate, copy and paste manually) the waitlist records because Domino cannot move attendees from one session to another.

We have over 1000 attendees in our waitlists.

Is he correct? Is this for real? We hope for a solution.

Comment: I had a moment to think about the technical issue and have come up with 2 ways you can deliver this functionality. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

How to do it depends on the way the documents are linked. But in any case it should be possible to relink the documents using code (formula/lotusscript/java).

The help of the Lotus designer contains a lot of information about application development. Another resource is [IBM developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/)

There are numerous Lotus related [blogs](http://planetlotus.org/)

From the Lotus Designer help:
MakeResponse: Makes one document a response to another document. The two documents must be in the same database.

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim docA As NotesDocument
Dim docB As NotesDocument
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView( "All documents" )
Set docA = view.GetFirstDocument
Set docB = view.GetNextDocument( docA )
Call docB.MakeResponse( docA )
docB.Form = "Response"
Call docB.Save( True, True )
```

Comment: Thank you Jasper! Do you have a URL (tutorial) that I can share with our developer?  Or maybe is there a question I can ask him to find out how the documents are linked, and then given his answer, I can share with him a tutorial how to do this "relink" process.  He sounds like he really doesn't know how. I think a "Move this Attendee to [dropdown of other sessions of this course]" control is enough for what we need, do you agree?

Comment: It really depends on the structure of the application. If this is a one time "conversion" the best way would be a lotusscript agent. There are a lot of resources on the internet. I have updated my answer with a few links

Comment: This will not be one-time, because registrants come in daily and sessions get opened weekly. (We're opening 50 new "in response to the demand" sessions before Christmas....) Tell us this: is the code to do this "relinking" only a matter of assigning the subdocument a new "parent docid" then saving it? I am an ex-SQL developer myself so I'd love any sample code. This sounds so basic.

Comment: Lotus is NoSQL :-) Can you tell me if the documents are linked as a response document? This would mean that the linked document has a $REF item that contains the key to the parent document. In that case it is a matter of changing the $REF item (I assume they are linked this way because the developer mentioned copy/paste)

Comment: I will ask him today. I sure hope the structure is $REF- simple. His clear "it is technologically impossible" answer is not inspiring anybody.  However, Jasper, I vaguely recall that certain field values of Courses and Sessions are saved in Attendees, i.e., in some reports, changing the course name won't "spread" to the preexisting attendee records. Certain Attendee reports still show the old course name.  It is insane.

Comment: It is precisely as simple as that. Note that while the ParentDocumentUNID can be *derived* from $REF, they are not the same thing, so assigning the UNID string to $REF won't work -- **you need to use the MakeResponse** method to reassign the parent document. (The $REF, and the actual document unique id, are CD structures made up of two DWORD-length TIMESTAMPs -- in other words, the value is a pair of numbers, and we can use a hex value represented as a string to do some things, but the strings aren't the real deal.)

Comment: I would suggest contracting a proper Domino developer to make this application change for you. Once they've examined the data structure and what actions you need to have in your system, coding the requisite processes to provide this functionality won't take long at all—it's "bread and butter" stuff for Domino.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that documents can be linked:
 - via keys, the soft way
 - hierarchically, using a document-response link (i.e. parent-child)

If there is only the logical link, using keys, you only have to adapt the key fields. If there is a "physical", document-response link, you can easily break and recreate that link. In LotusScript there is the NotesDocument.MakeResponse method to attach any document to a new parent. If both methods are used, redundant of course but practical when you need to recover some links, you need to do both changes. Usually, some key fields are repeated from parent to child

Just for testing purposes, you could try this:
- select a response document that you want to hang elsewhere
- Ctrl-X
- select the new parent document
- Ctrl-V

Do this in a test database, for the key fields won't be updated automatically. By the way: code can be written to repair the keys after pasting such a response document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep existing documents you could programmatically copy/duplicate them.
It's quite easy using copyAllItems method.

Look Domino help (with example) [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/6.5m2/help65_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/8cb932843a7bf85d85256d420050c8cc?OpenDocument)

You could iterate documents with notesView object (getFirstDocument() / getNextDocument() methods), iterate responses on notesdocument.responses method...

Trust us, it's possible, Domino is flexible :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways this data is linked in the data model you describe. If the data is linked through response document hierarchies it will be slightly different from key based document structures.

Show this to your developer and, he should literally be able to plug in the code to enable the "move attendees" requirements that you're talking about.

A few things to note.

- I am assuming that all the data you need to manipulate is in one database.
- I am taking your diagram you've provided literally.
- For key based document structures, you'll need to check the view and key values used o find attendee documents. Specifically check these 2 lines in the "MoveAttendeesKeyBased" sub:

  Set vwAttendeesByCourseID = db.GetView("(LkupAllAttendeesByCourseID)")

  Set dcAttendees = vwAttendeesbyCourseID.GetAllDocumentsByKey(docCourseFrom.CourseID(0), True)
- The code is designed to look at a field called "CourseID", "Status" and the value of "Wait Listed" for the status value of attendees to be moved.
- It took about 20 minutes to write both versions of this function.

For response based document structures

```
Sub MoveAttendeesResponseBased(docCourseFrom As notesDocument, docCourseTo As NotesDocument)
%REM
    A simple move attendees function if the relationship between courses and attendees is based on
    response document hierarchies
%END REM
    On Error Goto errHandle
    Dim dcAttendees As notesDocumentCollection
    Dim docAttendee As notesDocument
    Dim iAvailablePlaces As Integer
    Dim bMoved As Boolean

    If Not (docCourseFrom Is Nothing Or docCourseTo Is Nothing) Then        
        iAvailablePlaces = docCourseTo.availablePlaces(0)
        If 0 < iAvailablePlaces Then
            bMoved = False
            Set dcAttendees = docCourseFrom.Responses
            Set docAttendee = dcAttendees.GetFirstDocument
            While Not docAttendee Is Nothing And 0 < iAvailablePlaces
                If Ucase(Trim(docAttendee.Status(0)))= "WAIT LISTED" Then
                    Call docAttendee.MakeResponse(docCourseTo)
                    If docAttendee.Save(True,True) Then
                        iAvailablePlaces = iAvailablePlaces - 1
                        bMoved = True
                    End If
                End If
                Set docAttendee = dcAttendees.GetNextDocument(docAttendee)
            Wend
            If bMoved Then
                docCourseTo.availablePlaces = iAvailablePlaces
                Call docCourseTo.Save(True,False)
            End If
        End If
    End If  
    Exit Sub
errHandle:
    Messagebox Lsi_info(2) + " - " + Str(Err) + " : " + Error(Err) + ", at line " + Str(Erl)
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

For key based document structures

```
Sub MoveAttendeesKeyBased(docCourseFrom As notesDocument, docCourseTo As notesDocument)
%REM
    A simple move attendees function if the relationship between courses and attendees uses 
    (non-response) key based documents
%END REM
    On Error Goto errHandle
    Dim session As New notesSession
    Dim dcAttendees As notesDocumentCollection
    Dim docAttendee As notesDocument
    Dim iAvailablePlaces As Integer
    Dim bMoved As Boolean
    ' a view that lists attendees by Course ID
    Dim vwAttendeesByCourseID As notesView
    Dim db As notesDatabase

    If Not (docCourseFrom Is Nothing Or docCourseTo Is Nothing) Then        
        iAvailablePlaces = docCourseTo.availablePlaces(0)
        If 0 < iAvailablePlaces Then
            Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
            ' do a lookup of all attendees based on the CourseFrom document course id
            Set vwAttendeesByCourseID = db.GetView("(LkupAllAttendeesByCourseID)")
            ' this is the collection of all attendees under the CourseFrom document
            Set dcAttendees = vwAttendeesbyCourseID.GetAllDocumentsByKey(docCourseFrom.CourseID(0), True)
            bMoved = False
            Set docAttendee = dcAttendees.GetFirstDocument
            ' While there are attendee documents to process and there are available places to goto
            While Not docAttendee Is Nothing And 0 < iAvailablePlaces
                ' if the attendee's status is "Wait Listed" then move them
                If Ucase(Trim(docAttendee.Status(0)))= "WAIT LISTED" Then
                    ' Update the course ID for the Attendee
                    docAttendee.CourseID = docCourseTo.CourseID(0)
                    If docAttendee.Save(True,True) Then
                        ' decrement the available places
                        iAvailablePlaces = iAvailablePlaces - 1
                        bMoved = True
                    End If
                End If
                Set docAttendee = dcAttendees.GetNextDocument(docAttendee)
            Wend
            If bMoved Then
                ' available places may be >= 0. Just update the available places so you don't over book the course
                docCourseTo.availablePlaces = iAvailablePlaces
                Call docCourseTo.Save(True,False)
            End If
        End If
    End If  
    Exit Sub
errHandle:
    Messagebox Lsi_info(2) + " - " + Str(Err) + " : " + Error(Err) + ", at line " + Str(Erl)
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Key based documents are a little more work but I think are a better structure because you can easily move documents in databases and restore from backups, copy and paste. With response documents you may have issues restoring backups becasue response documents use parent document UNID's to associate themselves to, and also if you move an attendee by accident, it would be impossible to know which course to put the attendee back onto without the original course information, thus leading you back to a key based structure for documents.(But that's just my opinion).....